# Use Android phone as wireless adapter for Ubuntu desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, android, desktop-computer

Is there any way I could use my Android phone (rooted) as a wireless adapter for my Ubuntu desktop? Or share the data connection?

edit: Is there any full free ones?

Answer (score 4):

[Easy Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mstream.e2t) allows you to use your Android phone as the network device for Ubuntu. I have used it with both 3g and wifi providing the connection on the Android.

No need for root.

Has a free trial - no ssl allowed in trial.

Answer (score 1):

[Barnacle Wifi Tether](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.szym.barnacle&feature=nav_result) may work for your (unstated) phone model. It is free with a companion toggle widget for the home screen available. **Rooted phone required**, as you've stated you have.

The app hasn't been updated in 18 months, but back when I needed this functionality, I found the developer to be extremely helpful. Barnacle is now [open source](https://github.com/szym/barnacle), and not in active development.